# Logstash not working in Windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm new to ELK, sorry If I'm asking the basic question.
I have a setup of ELK in windows 10.
Java is already installed and JAVA_HOME path is set.

I have installed:

- Elasticsearch 5.6.1
- Kibana 5.6.1
- Logstash 5.6.1

When I'm testing the installation of ELK, Elasticsearch (http://localhost:9200)  and Kibana (http://localhost:5601/app/kibana) are up and running, but when I run the test command `logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'`, logstash shows the following error `**The system cannot find the path specified**`

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>   [FATAL] 2017-09-21 18:49:52.403 [main] runner - An unexpected error
>   occurred! {:error=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal
>   character in path at index 24: file:///D:/Trainings/ELK
>   stack/logstash-5.6.1/config/log4j2.properties,
>   :backtrace=>["java.net.URI.create(java/net/URI.java:852)",
>   "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)",
>   "RUBY.reconfigure(D:/Trainings/ELK
>   stack/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/logging/logger.rb:78)",
>   "org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex.synchronize(org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149)",
>   "RUBY.reconfigure(D:/Trainings/ELK
>   stack/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/logging/logger.rb:77)",
>   "RUBY.execute(D:/Trainings/ELK
>   stack/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:224)",
>   "RUBY.run(D:/Trainings/ELK
>   stack/logstash-5.6.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67)",
>   "RUBY.run(D:/Trainings/ELK
>   stack/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:204)",
>   "RUBY.run(D:/Trainings/ELK
>   stack/logstash-5.6.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132)",
>   "D_3a_.Trainings.ELK_20_stack.logstash_minus_5_dot_6_dot_1.lib.bootstrap.environment.(root)(D:\Trainings\ELK
>   stack\logstash-5.6.1\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:71)",
>   "D_3a_.Trainings.ELK_20_stack.logstash_minus_5_dot_6_dot_1.lib.bootstrap.environment.(root)(D_3a_/Trainings/ELK_20_stack/logstash_minus_5_dot_6_dot_1/lib/bootstrap/D:\Trainings\ELK
>   stack\logstash-5.6.1\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:71)"]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> 'file:///D:/Trainings/ELK stack/logstash-5.6.1/config/log4j2.properties'[24]
' '
```

Looks like part of logstash is failing to handle the space in your path, try removing the space from `../ELK stack/...`

Maybe open an issue with them on github about it as well. You are not the only one running into this issue, as can be seen https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-windows-paths-with-spaces-break-plugin-installation/93586

Comment: @Will....Thank you so much, I never thought space in folder name will cause this error